# How do I use 乱?

Tags: word-requests

For the sentence, 你别乱闹.
I think it means "do not randomly complain," but that doesn't sound right.
I can't pinpoint what 乱 means.

Answer (score 5):

乱 (adv): arbitrarily

1. on the basis of random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system.
2. without restraint in the use of authority; autocratically.

Example:

乱花錢 =  spend money arbitrarily (randomly, without restraint)

乱闹 = arbitrarily (without reason, without restraint)
making trouble

乱猜 = arbitrarily (randomly) guess

乱説 = arbitrarily (without reason, without restraint) say

*乱 (adv) = 随意地/ 随便地(randomly); 武断地 (arbitrarily); 胡乱地 (indiscriminadamentely)*

Answer (score 1):

In 《现代汉语词典（第七版）》, one of the senses provided of 亂/乱 is

> ... 5. <副> 任意，随便 | at random, haphazardly

And in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%82), we have this:

> ... 8. wildly; in an uncontrolled way; without order or reason; at random; haphazardly; having no direction or coherence; recklessly
>
> 亂說 / 乱说  ―  luànshuō  ―  to say whatever is on one's mind
>
> 亂舞 / 乱舞  ―  luànwǔ  ―  to dance in an unorganized, uncoordinated way

another way to say 乱闹 will be [胡鬧/胡闹](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%83%A1%E9%AC%A7#Chinese) (Click to see the Wiktionary page).

More examples:

你别[乱来](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%82%E4%BE%86#Chinese) (or [胡来](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%83%A1%E4%BE%86#Chinese))。 Don't mess around.

你别乱说 ([乱讲](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%82%E8%AC%9B#Chinese), or [胡说](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%83%A1%E8%AA%AA#Chinese))。 Don't talk nonsense.

这个词可不能[乱用](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%82%E7%94%A8#Chinese)。 This word must be used in the proper way.

那个人在到处[乱跑](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%82%E8%B7%91#Chinese)。 That person is running all over the place.